# Why is my JOptionPane not appearing when I use a Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I have narrowed down my problem: JOptionPane will not appear if I use a Scanner. For example, this works fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Before the dialog.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please.");
    System.out.println("After the dialog.");
}
```

Even this works, too:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Before the dialog.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please.");
    System.out.println("After the dialog.");
}
```

But, this does not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hi = butler.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Before the dialog.");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please.");
    System.out.println("After the dialog.");
}
```

In the last example, the program waits for input, then it displays "Before the dialog." After that, the program seems to freeze.

I tried closing the scanner before the creating the dialog, but that had no effect.

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe your actual code is different. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Is the JOptionPane hidden behind the IDE interface because the IDE has focus due to the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear after the input is read by the `Scanner`. It's just not appearing as the top level window. See [JOptionPane won't show its dialog on top of other windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438463/joptionpane-wont-show-its-dialog-on-top-of-other-windows) for how to solve this.