# Empty JFrame showing on screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I currently am using a `JOptionPane` to pop up a message and display it to the user. The message is not always on top of other windows so I put it in a dummy `JFrame` (`errorFrame`) and set `errorFrame` to always be on top. This works for keeping the `errorFrame` always on top, but it creates a second, empty frame in the upper right of the screen. The option pane appears at 100,100 just like I am setting the location of the dummy frame which contains it. Why is this second frame being created? All help is appreciated

UPDATE: I got the idea to put the `JOptionPane` inside of a `JFrame` from this post:
[JOptionPane won't show its dialog on top of other windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438463/joptionpane-wont-show-its-dialog-on-top-of-other-windows)

```
try {
    JFrame errorFrame = new JFrame();
    errorFrame.setVisible(true);
    errorFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    if (true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(errorFrame,
              "blah blah",
              "blahblahblah",
              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

        return true;
    }
    errorFrame.dispose();
}
```

Comment: as a temporary fix, I have setVisible to false and setDefaultCloseOperation to JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE however this seems bad practice as I am creating an invisible, unused JFrame

Comment: What do you want to happen? Just the JFrame and The JOptionPane?

Comment: Post a screenshot of your working code in your question

Comment: The problem you seem to be describing is actually an issue with your OS, I know, annoying :P

Comment: *"The message is not always on top of other windows"*  What is the parent component of the option pane?  1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a dummy frame, set the parent frame to be temporarily on top

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Parent");
if(test condition){
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    int choice = JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "blah blah","blahblahblah",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if(choice!=null)
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put setVisible() after dispose(), exchange them.